# Python writes to a buffer instead of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, output, stdout

I'm pretty new to a Python, but I've faced a weird behavior that I can't explain/solve.
Basically, I need to forward python script output to a file.

Example:

```
while True:
  print('tick')
  time.sleep(5)
```

then redirect output to the file

```
python test.py >> test.log 2>&1
```

But the thing is the file is empty until the script is finished.
Looks like it writes the output to some buffer and only at the end sends this buffer to a file.

This is totally unacceptable for me, as I have a script that is running 24/7 and in this case, I will never get proper logs. I need real-time writing to a file.

I know it might be fixed using

```
with open('test.log', mode='a') as log_file:
```

But in this case, I will lose the ability to view the result in the terminal.
Besides that, I will be strictly limited to a file specified inside of a script.

I suppose it is not actually Python issue, but more generic.
Still, is that possible to do instant writing to a file, just like I see it in the terminal?

Comment: You can change Python's buffering, but you likely also need to change the terminal /OS buffering. Have you considered making your script aware where it writes to? On Unix, scripts commonly treat the "path" - as stdout.

Comment: To log in python, you should use the implemented `logging` class where all functions do exist out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looks like it writes the output to some buffer

That's correct. You can disable this with [`flush=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), so:

```
while True:
  print('tick', flush=True)
  time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('log.log', 'w+') as log_file:    
print('tick', file=log_file)
```

In that way the print output will go to file instead stdout